# FragmentNavigator shared transition doesn't work

Tags: android, navigation, androidx

I'm Implementing navigation with the Navigation Architecture Component, trying to make transition between two fragments on `ImageView` so I added this `android:transitionName="trans"` to the `ImageView` in my xml file at the first fragment and the second one , and adding this to my Java code

```
FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
    .addSharedElement(imageView, "trans")
    .build();
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_addFragment,
     null,
     null,
     extras);
```

Trying also using `Direction` like this :

```
MainFragmentDirections.ActionMainFragmentToAddFragment toAddFragment = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToAddFragment();
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(toAddFragment, extras);
```

But there is no animation. the code above is from the offcial [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#shared-element).

Comment: I have found the same issue with ```androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0``` and ```androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0```

Answer (score 0):

try to add in your fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
        }
    }
```